# Data is not showing on Radial Dendrogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to use Radial Dendrogram for showing my data on it. but it does not show any data on it. 
https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-dendrogram

I have created the HTML and javascript file in which I use the above link code. But nothing is displaying. when I remove last part of code i.e svg.remove something is showing at the corner but a little. Please guide me how will it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Minimal D3 Example</title>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hierarchy.v1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       var tree = d3.tree();
   </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>This is a Test Graph</h1>
 <script src="data.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="code.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
</html>

const root = tree(d3.hierarchy(data)
  .sort((a, b) => (a.height - b.height) ||    
  a.data.name.localeCompare(b.data.name)));

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "932")
  .attr("height", "932")
  .style("padding", "10px")
  .style("box-sizing", "border-box")
  .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

const g = svg.append("g");

const link = g.append("g")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#555")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
.selectAll("path")
.data(root.links())
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.linkRadial()
      .angle(d => d.x)
      .radius(d => d.y));

const node = g.append("g")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
.selectAll("g")
.data(root.descendants().reverse())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", d => `
    rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90})
    translate(${d.y},0)
  `);

node.append("circle")
  .attr("fill", d => d.children ? "#555" : "#999")
  .attr("r", 2.5);

node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "0.31em")
  .attr("x", d => d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? 6 : -6)
  .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? "start" : 
"end")
  .attr("transform", d => d.x >= Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : null)
  .text(d => d.data.name)
  .filter(d => d.children)
  .clone(true).lower()
  .attr("stroke", "white");

 document.body.appendChild(svg.node());

 const box = g.node().getBBox();


 svg.remove()
 .attr("width", box.width)
 .attr("height", box.height)
 .attr("viewBox", `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same dataset?

Comment: yes, @wentjun, for the time being, I am using the exact same dataset when it displays properly then I will use my own dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your code is missing a few variables, `tree`, `radius`, and `height`.

Do remember to include them on your javascript file, as they are needed to render the tree. You may replace the value I have given for `width` with any other value that is suitable for your use case. In addition, you did not include any data for the tree to render.

```
const width = 932;
const radius = width / 2;
const tree = d3.cluster().size([2 * Math.PI, radius - 100]);
```

In addition, you may remove this chunk of code, as they are not needed.

```
// remove the below 

document.body.appendChild(svg.node());

const box = g.node().getBBox();


svg.remove()
 .attr("width", box.width)
 .attr("height", box.height)
 .attr("viewBox", `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);
```

You may refer to the demo over [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d2ncgw9e/). I have used the data from https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-dendrogram to render the dendrogram.

Comment: is it possible to show the full graph? now it's showing half.